# How to create a csv file virtually without any physical file / path defined?

Tags: python, csv, odoo-12, edi

Need to create a csv file and convert it into byte like data for sending as EDI doc. I am trying to achieve this without having a physical file  because location/path is unknown. Let me know if there is anyway we could achieve.

```
with open(
    "/home/some path/*.dat", "r+", newline="\n"
) as write_f:
    data_file = csv.writer(write_f, delimiter=';')
    header_vals = ["header values"]

    query = """data fetching query"""

    data_file.writerow(header_vals)
    self.env.cr.execute(query)
    data_vals = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    data_file.writerows(data_vals)
    po_data = write_f.read(1024)

return po_data
```

Try 1: Instead of path, tried IO objects(BytesIO/StringIO)

```
data_file = BytesIO()
data_write = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter=';')

header_vals = ["header values"]

query = """data fetching query"""

data_write.writerow(header_vals)
self.env.cr.execute(query)
data_vals = self.env.cr.fetchall()
data_write.writerows(data_vals)
```

Received the error at writerow: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: You could use `io` library for in-memory streaming. You can create a `BytesIO` from a file. https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Comment: @BijayRegmi Tried the way you suggested. But while writing(used writerow as in above code) I got the following error:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Would you add some code of how you tried it and what you intend? I am not sure how exactly you are streaming from the file to pipe the stream into bytestream for EDI

Comment: You could just build and append a string object manually. Why do you want to use csv writer?

Comment: Not necessary. Used csv writer because, I thought it would be easy to structure the object's data.. which is a list of dictionary vals.
Need output bytes structured as HEADER - ROWS. Also, columns separated by ; 
Haven't handled string/io objects much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BytesIO` behaves like a file in binary (!) mode. You need to write bytes to it.

But a `csv.writer` cannot write bytes, it only writes strings. That's the error message you see.

```
from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buffer, delimiter=';')

header_vals = ['column_1', 'column_2']
writer.writerow(header_vals)

print(buffer.getvalue())

# => 'column_1;column_2\r\n'
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I tried StringIO. But didn't know getvalue() function. Used read() which was empty !

Comment: @Nirmalraj https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek